# What is the meaning of plus symbols to the left of UML roles?

Tags: uml, roles

What is the meaning of the plus symbols to the left of the roles *examiner* and *examinee* in figure 4.13(c) on p. 62 of the textbook
*UML@Classroom* by Seidl, Scholz, Huemer & Kappel (Springer, 2015)? This figure is reproduced below.

[image: Figure 4.13(c) from the textbook UML@Classroom]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The + means **public**. Apparently, code outside the `Person` class is allowed to access a person's `examinee`s and `examiner`s directly.

The `+` symbol is also used to indicate public class operations, for example. The other options are `#` for protected, `~` for package, and `-` for private.

Comment: I understand what it means for an attribute or operation to be public, since it translates to the `public` keyword of fields and methods in Java. But what does it mean for a role to be public? What does it translate to in Java?

Comment: @EvanAad the role `examiner` at the opposite end of the association is a property.  A property is like an attribute.  You could as well show `+examiner:Person[*]` as class member, although it would be far less visual and more ambiguous in the case of a reflexive association. In java, you would code this design with class `Person` having two fields which correspond to a collection of Person: `examiner` and `examinee` - this works well in Java because of the reference semantic of objects

Comment: And IIRC a `^` for inherited ones...